# Protocol stack and destruction order in C++

Tags: c++, network-programming

In general when we implement a protocol stack in C++ we have that each layer needs to hold a reference to the two neighbour layers, e.g.:

```
HTTP <---> TCP <---> IP
```

This reference could be implemented with C++ references, `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr` combination or raw pointers, e.g.:

```
class TCP
{
  ...
  TCP& protocol_above;
  IP& protocol_below;
}
```

If we use smart pointers, obviously we need some weak pointers to break cyclic dependencies. This is undesirable, as we need to continuously check if the weak pointer has expired, or lock it.

If we use raw pointers or references, it means we have some other mechanism in place to take care of the objects ownership and destruction. Let's assume this mechanisms destroys all objects in the protocol stack when all of them are unused (e.g., no other references or pointers to them, besides the neighbours protocols in the stack). I can see two cases here:

1. If we use raw pointers, we are still able to check if any of them is set to `nullptr`. Would it be necessary? As long as the protocol stack is active, we have 100% guarantees that none of the layers is destroyed.
2. References are a similar case, except that we explicitly show our certainty that they will be valid during lifetime of each layer.

But is this a good practice? Even if our ownership/destruction mechanism is perfect, it implies a **destruction order**. I.e., no layer of the protocol stack is destroyed as long as the stack is active, but during destruction, as layers are mutually referenced, it means we are getting some invalid references (or pointers set to null) in the process.

This could be fine as long as we have the guarantee no destructor is invoking the references to the neighbour protocols.

All in all, we are faced with either using some raw/weak pointer whose expiration we need to check continuously, or using references that we consider valid... except at destruction.

What would be the best design pattern here? I feel inclined to use references, and be careful none of them is invoked in any layer object destructor. Or is it a code smell?

Otherwise, if this is considered a bad practice, is there any proper way to implement this in C++ without regularly checking the validity of pointers? In other languages like java it is fine to have cyclic dependencies, and the garbage collector will take care of it. In general, we don't have this luxury in C++ (at least in the standard library).

EDIT. Maybe the focus of my question was misunderstood. I am asking about the best pattern to implement protocol stacks ownership in C++. They inherently lead to cyclic dependencies. Shared/weak pointers is not really convenient as we need to constantly check validity of weak link.

In old C implementations I have seen, the common approach is having some factory class taking care of the allocation/deallocation of all layers in the stack (therefore each layer assumes validity of pointers to neighbor ones). This would probably be some antipattern in C++.

Comment: Why doesn't HTTP own TCP own IP ?  If a higher layer is torn down it can notify the layer below to clean up and "NULL out" any parent references.  If a lower layer is about to be torn down it can notify the parent and then parent can then perform the destruction of the children.

Comment: It would be possible. But it is not relevant to my question. We still need to check for the validity of the pointer.

Comment: My point is you need to justify (in the question) why you need 2 way strong links - this could be a design error.

Comment: It is arguable if two neighbor layers should hold strong links to each other. In any case, if one of the links is weak, we still need to check validity of this link. Which is perhaps a bit inconvenient compared to other solutions.